# R bigpca package not available

Tags: r, package

I tried to install package of bigpca in R studio. However it was failed. The information said:

```
> install.packages("bigpca")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘bigpca’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)
```

Then I tried to find which version of R works, but could not find the sure answer. Could anyone help me how to fix this issue? Or any other way to install this package? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the most recent [check on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_bigpca.html)  which was today  resulted in an ERROR:

[image]

Therefore, I am assuming that the package is suspended and the maintainer has been informed about it. You can either wait for the maintainer to fix the error or you could try downloading an older version from CRAN.